# Condição Se em Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou a tentar criar uma condição em excel em que se o texto numa folha for = sim então faz uma acção, eu tentei fazer assim mas diz que é um referencia circular.

```
=SE('Dados do paciente'!N3="Sim";0; A3='Dados do paciente'!A3)
```

A coisa é que ele diz que é um referencia circular mas quando eu analiso ele dá Sim=Sim logo deveria depois deveria realizar a operação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qual deveria ser a ação da fórmula para quando SeNão:

```
=SE('Dados Pacientes'!N2="Sim";'Dados Pacientes'!A2;"Faz Alguma Coisa Quando For Não ou Não tiver Respostas")
```

No caso:

`'Dados Pacientes'!N2="Sim"` => Refere ao contexto de condição. Ou seja, o campo "'Dados Pacientes'!N2" tem que ser igual a "Sim".

Caso seja positivo, **O campo onde está ocorrendo a condição**, irá receber o valor que estiver no campo `"'Dados Pacientes'!A2"`.

Caso negativo irá receber o texto `"Faz Alguma Coisa Quando For Não ou Não tiver Respostas"`.

***Na fórmula você não precisa referenciar o campo que irá receber o retorno.
Tipo o Seu **"A3="*****

Planilha Chamda 48H.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Planilha dados Paciente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: e qual o motivo de este não funcionar
=SE(OR('chamada 48h'!T3="Sim";'Chamada 15 dias'!M3="Sim"; 'chamada 30 dias'!V3="Sim"); 'Dados do paciente'!A3) ?

Comment: srsrs, isso já seria outra questão. Mas vamos lá. Rapaz, primeiro define se seu excel está em Pt, ou inglês. Pois, OR é inglês. No pt será OU.
Olha um exemplo: ```=SE(OU(B5="Sim";C5="Sim"; D5="Sim");B2;"Resposta é Não")```

Comment: Pensei que aceitasse os dois, erro meu. era exatamente esse o erro

Answer (score 1):

No caso do **SE** em Excel a construção é assim:

```
=SE([CONDICIONAL];[RESULTADO CASO VERDADEIRO];[RESULTADO CASO FOR FALSO)
```

Exemplo:

```
=SE(1=1;"Igual";"Diferente")
```

**O resultado do SE sempre vai aparecer no campo em que você está realizando a fórmula**, não é preciso informar qual campo o resultado trará o resultado, por isso essa parte é desnecessária: A3='Dados do paciente'!A3

O correto seria:

```
=SE('Dados do paciente'!N3="Sim";0;'Dados do paciente'!A3)
```

A referência circular se dá porque você está buscando o resultado do seu **SE** na no seu próprio **SE** então fica um "looping" infinito, você vai ter que escolher um resultado ou um outro valor como resultado "falso/negativo" do seu **SE**, por exemplo:

```
=SE('Dados do paciente'!N3="Sim";0;1)
```

Ou

```
=SE('Dados do paciente'!N3="Sim";0;'Dados do paciente'!B3)
```